# can't change the a variable value in the javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am new to Javascript, I am confused about the code below for hours.
I wanna know why i can't assign the value of result to htmlContent.
Thanks!

```
var htmlContent = fs.readFileSync(program.file);

restler.get('http://google.com').on('complete', function(result) {
    if (result instanceof Error) {
        util.puts('Error: ' + result.message);
    } else {
       htmlContent = result;
    }
});
console.log(htmlContent);
```

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of **async**! You can't do that.

Comment: I am not familiar with async of javascript.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that the line starting with `restler.get` begins before the `console.log`, but it doesn't finish before it necessarily.

You should put your `console.log` inside the `restler.get` call.

Comment: I know what you mean. But I just wanna get the result, and use the result value in other function.

Comment: is there any method to return the result value?

Comment: Then your `else` branch would need code like `nextFunction(result)`. Because the function is asynchronous, return values are not very useful, so you will want to pass your value to your next function.

Comment: Thanks, I got it. It is kind of different comparing javascript coding logic with other language~

Comment: Great! You may want to read up on asynchronous JavaScript in order to get a better idea of how to structure your code.

Answer (score 0):

I would look up the concept of futures and promises in JS, this might help clear up some fundamentals:
http://monochrome.sutic.nu/2012/04/06/javascript-futures.html

When you are using continuations in JS (a requirement in node.js especially), you really need to get your head around them.

Comment: Thanks~I am looking at it!

Answer (score 0):

Here, your function inside the `.on()` will be called asynchronously (in simple words it will get executed when "complete" event occurs i.e. some later time) and you are using `console.log(htmlContent)` is regular function call, so you can not set `htmlContent` value inside the function this way.

If you want to use `result` value in any other function then you should pass this value to your next function. I hope this will work.